# Dynamically attach JavaScript functions

Tags: jquery, widget

I've read through some of the other similar posts, but can't find a solution to my (simple?) problem.

I am building a JQuery Widget.  I want to allow the user to specify which JQuery animation type must be used to show certain things.

Basically, I want to change the function that must run on the fly.

For example:

```
var animation = this.options.animationType;
$("#myDiv").animation();
```

(I know the code is incorrect, I just wanted to show the concept)

The selected animation type must then run

Any ideas, is this even possible?

Thank you,
Michelle

Answer (score 0):

You can only do something like this by creating your own [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/). If it's done correctly, the user could write something like this:

```
var options = { animationType: "bounce" };
$("#myDiv").animation(options);
```

To create jQuery plugins with ease, you can jumpstart them using [Starter](http://starter.pixelgraphics.us/) or the jQuery [Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/). Don't forget to read the documentation on how to create plugins (loads of stuff about that can be found on Google or on SO).

Answer (score 0):

See if you want something like this:

you have created a jquery function here:

```
$.fn.center = function(){
   this.css('top',($(window).height()/2-$(this).height()/2)+'px');
   this.css('left',($(window).width()/2-$(this).width()/2)+'px');
   return this;
};
```

and call it like this:

```
$('myElem').center();
```

`$.fn.center` will center the elem which calls it.